# Got a fault in my google maps code

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

I am making a google maps for my website so you can view where each user is.
This works perfect only when you click on an icon of someone it will show you the same every time i cant understand it am i doing something wrong?

```
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/xml.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("USER");
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map; 
    var users = [];
    function initialize() { 
      var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 9, 
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.1424, 5.09428), 
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
      var id = x[i].getElementsByTagName("USERID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['USERNAME'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("USERNAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['CITY'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("CITY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['COUNTRY'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['IMAGE'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['IMAGEPIN'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("IMAGEPIN")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['LAT'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("LAT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['LONG'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("LONG")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['DATETIME'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATETIME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['TWITTER'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("TWITTER")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['FA'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("FA")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['ACTIVEUSER'+id] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("ACTIVEUSER")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      users['myLatlng'+id] = new google.maps.LatLng(users['LAT'+id],users['LONG'+id]);
      users['content'+id] = '<div style="width:220px;"><img id="avatar"style="margin-right: 5px;" src="' + users['IMAGE'+id] + '"></img>' + 
        '<b>' + users['USERNAME'+id] + '</b><br />' + 
        users['CITY'+id] + '<br />' + users['COUNTRY'+id] + '<br />' + 
        '<i>' + users['DATETIME'+id] + '</i><br />' +
        '<a href="http://www.furaffinity.net/user/' + users['FA'+id] + '" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.kinzart.com/images/fur-affinity-icon.png" Alt="Twitter" width="30" height="30"></a>' +
        '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + users['TWITTER'+id] + '/" target="_blank"><img src="http://biophiliccities.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/twitterICON.png" Alt="Twitter" width="30" height="30"></a>';
      users['window'+id] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: users['content'+id]});
      users['marker'+id] = new google.maps.Marker({ position: users['myLatlng'+id], map: map, title: users['USERNAME'+id], icon: users['IMAGEPIN'+id]});
      google.maps.event.addListener(users['marker'+id], 'click', function() { infoWindow.setContent(users['content'+id]); infoWindow.open(map, users['marker'+id]) });
      }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: you should check out jquery

Comment: Please add example content of `var x`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you setup your event listener within the loop, it ends up that every iteration of the loop sets the infowindow content to be whatever the last value of `users['content'+id]` is.  You need to look into using closures in your code.

Here's another way of doing it that should work:

```
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
      ...  // trimmed for brevity
      users['marker'+id] = new google.maps.Marker({ position: users['myLatlng'+id], map: map, title: users['USERNAME'+id], icon: users['IMAGEPIN'+id]});
      bindInfoWindow(users['marker'+id], users['content'+id]);
}
```

then have this function:

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, content) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infoWindow.setContent(content); 
        infoWindow.open(map, marker) 
    });
}
```